# Printing in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, pagination

This is pankaj vishwakarma a vb.net developer, I am currently working on the printing project.Here I am creating a custom paper on the printer via code and then trying to print the text on a specified location . It does not print. After trying many time i found that printable area is not changed but it is changing height and width as custom paper  still it's 
printable area remains the same as previous paper

Comment: `Psychic Mode` ON. Hey Mr. Vishwakarma, Welcome to StackOverFlow Community. You must add more details regarding your question so you will be helped.

Comment: more details like what code or what